# Adding constant parameter to AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: nsurlrequest, afnetworking-2

I'm currently having to make multiple requests in order to retrieve information from a backend using API calls.

One of the parameters that has to be included each time, in any request, is a parameter "access_token".

I wondered if there is any functionality in AFNetworking 2.0 that I could take advantage of, and include a parameter in all backend calls, rather than having to type it in each time?

I hope this is clear... If not, I can always try to re-write my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I actually utilised access_token in a different way, by adding it as an authorization header, rather than sending it as a parameter (some API work was needed).

Though, for anyone that does want to include a parameter on every network call, I couldn't find a method on AFNetworking for immediate use, so created a category and added my own method:

```
- (void)addBaseParametersToNetworkCall {
  [[self requestSerializer] setValue:@"aValue" forKey:@"aKey"];
  // NOTE: "self" in this case is [AFNetwork class].
}
```

And this method would just be called before any network call. Another approach would be to keep an NSMutableDictionary on the AFNetworking (sub)class, and add your parameters to this. Then, instead of specifying each value within the |addBaseParametersToNetworkCall| method, it would just work like so:

```
- (void)addBaseParametersToNetworkCall {
  for id entry in [self parametersToSend] {
    [[self requestSerializer] setValue:[[self parametersToSend] objectForKey:entry] forKey:entry];
    // NOTE: "self" in this case is [AFNetwork class].
  }
}
```